# Can sfdx force:source:delete be used against a production org?

Tags: salesforcedx

Just wondering if anyone has tried this and if so how does validation come into play?

I can't find any information or documentation stating whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 4):

No, You can't delete in production using **sfdx force:source:delete**.

As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm), it 
Deletes source files from your project and from a non-source-tracked org, such as a sandbox.

To delete from production, use destructiveChanges.xml. Follow these articles:-

1. [Deleting Files from an Organization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm)

The package.xml file is a project manifest that lists all the components to retrieve or deploy. Although you can use package.xml to add components, it’s not sufficient to delete them. To delete files, create a delete manifest that’s called destructiveChanges.xml. The format of the delete manifest is the same as package.xml, except that wildcards aren’t supported.

Comment: The question was about force:source:delete, not force:org:delete.

Comment: Thanks, corrected it now.

Comment: Thank you for your response. According to this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm force:source:deploy can be used to deploy changes to production, is there any corresponding way to delete changes that you know of or does this have to be done via the metadata api?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work because it requires you to run tests as with any prod deployment, but there are no option to force:source:delete to run tests.
destructiveChanges.xml is problematic because it always fails with an error if the component you're trying to delete doesn't exist. force:source:delete is more lenient.

Answer (score 3):

I had a required to remove unused apex classes from production. Since sfdx force:source:delete is not working for production org, So performed below steps (in VS code) and able to remove apex classes from production:

- Created manifest project in VS code and created package.xml with apex classes to be deleted
- executed `sfdx force:source:retrieve` command to retrieve the code.
- In meta.xml file for each class, changed status to deleted.  `<status>deleted</status>`
- Executed below deploy command and classes removed from production.

  sfdx force:source:deploy -x "sourcePath\manifest\package.xml"  -l RunLocalTests

Answer (score 2):

From the forcedotcom/cli repo's issues I have found: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/188.

sfdx force:source:deploy -x package.xml does not currently support destructive changes but this feature is planned to be implemented in the coming months.

Currently sfdx force:mdapi:deploy does support destructiveChangesPre/Post.xml to delete files.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to remove metadata with force:source:deploy was recently introduced with the addition of `--predestructivechanges destructiveChangesPre.xml` and `--postdestructivechanges destructiveChangesPost.xml`.

This can be specified in a constructive build, where package.xml has content to be deployed, or with an empty package.xml, as with traditional ant based destructive changes.

E.g. `>sfdx force:source:deploy --testlevel RunLocalTests -x package.xml --predestructivechanges destructiveChangesPre.xml -u my-org-alias`

I have successfully removed an Apex Class from production with this.

See CLI docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_deploy

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sfdx` delete command in Production as well but you should define your test level.

You can read more at `sfdx` command [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_delete)

Here is example:

```
sfdx force:source:delete -m ApexClass:<ClassName> -l RunLocalTests
```

In above example I tried with run local test.

Answer (score 0):

And here is how you can delete metadata in the year 2023 from production orgs: `sf project delete source`. For two Apex classes this would look like so:

```
sf project delete source --metadata ApexClass:Foo,ApexClass:Bar
```

This would run all the unit tests. Documentation with more options [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_project_delete_source_unified).